# Swaping two different splitpanes on a single jframe

Tags: java

Please guys, I have two split pane, say pane A and pane B, I placed a button on pane A such that if the button is clicked,pane A is hidden and pane B becomes visible, but each time i try doing this I get an error which says:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Do not use this method  
    at net.java.dev.designgridlayout.DesignGridLayoutManager.removeLayoutComponent(DesignGridLayoutManager.java:122).
```

Answer (score 1):

The description is in no way sufficient to give a profound answer. But based on the [documentation of the method that causes the error](https://designgridlayout.java.net/apidocs/net/java/dev/designgridlayout/DesignGridLayoutManager.html#removeLayoutComponent%28java.awt.Component%29), it seems that removing components from such a layout is simply not supported.

You could use a different layout manager. Maybe a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) could be helpful. In doubt, it should always be possible to introduce an additional container. I'll try to sketch the idea here, although nobody knows what your code looks like:

```
class GUI {
    private JPanel containerA = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1));

    void init() {
        ...
        // Here "grid" is the component that has the DesignGridLayout:
        grid.add(containerA);
        containerA.add(splitPaneA);
    }

    void whenTheButtonIsClicked() {
        containerA.removeAll();
        containerA.add(splitPaneB);
        containerA.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: if(event.get Source()==button){
       get pass=new String(pass field.get Password());
    get text= text field.get Text();    
 if((get text.equals(""))||(get pass.equals(""))){
    invalid_input.set Text("PLEASE INPUT DETAILS");    
 }
 else if (!"". equals(get text) || (!"". equals(get pass))){
      pane.set Visible(false);
       q panel.set J splitPane().set Visible(true);
       
       
}
 
   }
     }
  }

Comment: @user3537071 You should remove this (unreadable) comment and try to edit your question accordingly. (And, preferably, for future questions, provide the relevant code right from the beginning - preferably in form of an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This really helps to quickly receive good and helpful answers)

Comment: or does it mean design grid layout does not support removal of parent components from j frame,i said so because i  saw a method like this in the source code it looks like this...public void remove Layout Component(Component parent)
  {
    throw new Illegal Argument Exception("Do not use this method");
  }

Comment: @user3537071 See the documentation that I linked: **"Do not remove components via the parent container's Container.remove(Component) method; removing components from a DesignGridLayout-managed container is not supported."**

Comment: so what do you suggest i do now@Marco

Comment: this has been an embargo on my project progress for a while now,i really need to get it sorted,though am not yet an advanced java programmer,thanks for your help so far,i just hope i get a positive answer from you soonest@Marco

Comment: this has been an embargo on my project progress for a while now,i really need to get it sorted,though am not yet an advanced java programmer,thanks for your help so far,i just hope i get a positive answer from you soonest@Marco

Comment: @user3537071 I wrote one possible suggestion. In any case, you should read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the suggestion you posted did not work at all,but is there any way i can hide a component that uses design grid layout?i read about the layout and saw the remove method that has being hindering the component from been removed or should i go look for another layout?@Marco

Comment: Obviously, your code is somewehere calling `remove()` on a component that was added to your design grid layout before; DesignGridLayout does not allow that. Posting the full relevant code in your question would help analysing your actual problem!